# onKeyDown() event not triggered when in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I capture Key Events (from an external keyboard) within my App. I use `onKeyDown()` method from `Activity`. In my app I switch between different Fragments. If I am in a normal `Fragment` then Activity's `onKeyDown()` is triggered when pressing buttons. But when I use a `DialogFragment` as a Dialog then pressing the button does not trigger `Activity's`onKeyDown()` any more.

Here some sample code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun onClick(view: View) {
// a) Key Event works if adding it via a fragment transaction by my own
//        val fragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance()
//        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
//        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fr_container, fragment, fragment.javaClass.name)
//        fragmentTransaction.commit()

// b) Key Event doesn't work if showing as a dialog
        val fragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance()
        fragment.show(supportFragmentManager, fragment.javaClass.name)

    }

    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        Log.i(javaClass.name, "onKeyDown() keyCode: $keyCode")
        return true
    }
}
```

And my two fragments:

```
class MyNormalFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_normal, container, false)
    }
}


class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_dialog, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MyDialogFragment()
    }
}
```

As soon as I call **a)** `show()` to open the `MyDialogFragment` then the key events are not captured any more. But if I open `MyDialogFragment` **b)** via custom Fragments transaction then the key events are still captured, but my Fragment isn't shown as a Dialog any more.

What do I have to do to let the event also trigger when my dialog is displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Dialog is shown in/as a separate Window, so your Activity doesn't have the focus for keypresses any more. However, the Dialog has it's own onKeyDown method, so you can make use of that.

Comment: This is a lifesaving answer. I was pulling my hair off until I found this answer. I've simply created `private class DialogExtended extends Dialog` and put my `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` logic into this and it's working as I expect it to be!

Answer (score 6):

Ridcully's answer is right. I just wanted to post what I changed inside `MyDialogFragment` to keep on capturing key events:

```
class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {
    private val keyEventListener = DialogInterface.OnKeyListener { dialog, keyCode, event ->
        Log.i(javaClass.name, "onKey() keyCode: $keyCode")
        true
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        dialog.setOnKeyListener(keyEventListener)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_dialog, container, false)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        dialog.setOnKeyListener(null)
        super.onDestroyView()
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MyDialogFragment()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a simple DialogInterface.OnKeyListener directly on DialogFragment

Comment: Can you explain your answer?